# How merge 2 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a 2 pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
 A0 B0 C0
 A1 B1 C1
 A2 B2 C2
 A3 B3 C3
```

and

```
 A2 D0 E0
 A0 D1 E1
 A3 D2 E2
 A1 D3 E3
```

How make this:

```
A0 B0 C0 D1 E1
A1 B1 C1 D3 E3
A2 B2 C2 D0 E0
A3 B3 C3 D2 E2
```

Comment: Does [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10783/how-do-i-merge-two-data-frames-in-python-pandas#:~:text=If%20you%20split%20the%20DataFrame,function%20or%20the%20concat%20function.&text=For%20more%20complex%20merging%20options,join%20and%20concat%20pandas%20tutorial.&text=That%20have%20the%20same%20column%20names.) help?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( [['A0', 'B0', 'C0'],
        ['A1', 'B1', 'C1'],
        ['A2', 'B2', 'C2'],
     ['A3', 'B3', 'C3']])

df1.columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']


df2 = pd.DataFrame([['A2', 'D0', 'E0'],
                   ['A0', 'D1', 'E1'],
                   ['A3', 'D2', 'E2'],
                   ['A1', 'D3', 'E3']])
df2.columns = ['c1', 'c4', 'c5']

df1.merge(df2, on = 'c1', how = 'left')
```

Output:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   A0  B0  C0  D1  E1
1   A1  B1  C1  D3  E3
2   A2  B2  C2  D0  E0
3   A3  B3  C3  D2  E2
```